# RNN instead of a PID controller

Tags: pid, raspberry-pi, artificial-intelligence

I am building a drone using the raspberry pi and I am using 6*PID controllers to control the speed and the value for each angle, can I use a recurrent neural network (RNN) or other neural network to stabilize the angles. If so what can the training data be? What type of neural network (NN) is best suited for this kind of application?

Comment: What do you mean by "drove"?

Comment: Drone sorry, that was a typo !

Comment: There are quite a few academic results that come up when googling "neural network PID".  Why aren't those results helpful to you?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I already saw many of them, but most use the nn to tune the Ki,Kp,Kd values no the control action itself.

Comment: If you don't want to use a PID or a [fuzzy logic controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_control_system), you could look into [On Replacing PID Controller with Deep Learning Controller for DC Motor System](http://www.joace.org/uploadfile/2015/0408/20150408032023512.pdf).

Comment: Thank you for the response and the link to the article, 4 years after the question almost :D